# How to crop screenshot or image (.png) in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, easyimage

1. Consider a image file .png
2. Consider you have the xy-cords of some element like x:400, y:500
3. Consider you have the size of image to be cropped: width: 50, height: 20

I have below snippet from nodejs pack easyimage and I have installed ImageMagick too.
**When I run below code, it just passes but unable to crop image.**

```js
easyimage.crop(
  {
    src: "F:/screenshot.png",  // Contains fullscreen image
    dst: "F:/screenshot.png",  // New image with cropped name
    x: 400,
    y: 500,
    cropwidth: 50,
    cropheight: 20,
    gravity: "North-West",
  },
  (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) throw err
  }
)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use `sharp` for this and it works pretty well

Try this

```js
const sharp = require('sharp')

sharp('./kangta.jpg')
    .extract({ left: 0, top: 0, width: 100, height: 100 })
    .toFile('./kangta.new.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    })
```

sharp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Answer (score 1):

Here I extend the example given above with a Puppeteer screenshot that gets split/cropped into multiple images with Sharp:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const sharp = require('sharp');

// original image
let originalImage = 'originalImage.jpg';

// file name for cropped image
let outputImage = 'croppedImage.jpg';

let outputConcat = '';

async function run(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true})
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'originalImage.jpg', fullPage:true});
    await browser.close();
        
    var sizeOf = require('image-size');
    var dimensions = sizeOf('originalImage.jpg');

    console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);

    const printText = (newHeight, newTop, imageIndex) => {      
        console.log('newHeight: ' + newHeight + ', newTop: ' + newTop + ', imageIndex: ' + imageIndex);
    };

    const cropImage = (newHeight, newTop, imageIndex) => {
          sharp('originalImage.jpg')
          .extract({left: 0, width: dimensions.width, height: newHeight, top: newTop})
          .toFile(outputConcat.concat(imageIndex, outputImage))
        };

    var remainingTop = dimensions.height;
    var cumulitiveTop = 0;

    var amountOfImages = Math.ceil(dimensions.height / 1080);

    for (let i = 0; i < amountOfImages; i++) 
    {
        if(remainingTop >= 1080)
        {           
            cropImage(1080, cumulitiveTop, i);
            //printText(1080, cumulitiveTop, i); 
        }
        else
        {
            cropImage(remainingTop, dimensions.height - remainingTop, i);
            //printText(remainingTop, dimensions.height - remainingTop, i); 
            
            break;
        }
        
        remainingTop = remainingTop - 1080;
        cumulitiveTop += 1080;
    }   
};

run();
```